# File Upload with PHP using Image_moo

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a function that suppose to get a image file from the **POST** request. I'm using [image_moo](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo) as a external library to resize the image before saving.

**Here's my function**

```
$dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/refundstylesheet/uploads/images/' . $_FILES['upfile']['name'];
$temp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];

$this->image_moo->load($temp_file)->resize(350,350)->save($dest, TRUE);
```

I don't get any error message, it simply doesn't save the image on the server.

echo $dest:** /var/www/html/refundstylesheet/uploads/images/image.png
echo $temp_file:** /tmp/phpFIQp6S

I did all the necessary [verifications](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) with the uploaded file before reachs this function.

Comment: `dest` should be `$dest`

Comment: *"I don't get any error message"* - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: That was just a mistake while pasting the code. But on my original source code is correct.

Comment: If you have typos in the code here everyone will chase those. Please correct your post so that we can get the real issue.

Comment: This image_moo library does some image editing, i guess. Do you have the `php-gd` extension installed and enabled in your php config (or maybe the `php-imagick` extension, don't know which they use). It would be helpful if you could get an error message

Comment: @RonnyCoolen php-imagick I'm sure that's not the case. I'll check if uses php-gd that you metioned. Therefore I didn't do any previous configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem installing php-gd extension. Ronny's comment helped me. Since  **image_moo** library does some image editing it needs this **dependency**. You may install this dependency simply executing the command bellow **(linux)**:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

Check if is installed with phpinfo() and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an error

> Notice: Use of undefined constant dest

maybe codeigniter handles this different

you should replace this:

```
$this->image_moo->load($temp_file)->resize(350,350)->save(dest, TRUE);
```

with that:

```
$this->image_moo->load($temp_file)->resize(350,350)->save($dest, TRUE);
```

You have defined a variable `$dest` but you are trying to use an undefined [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) `dest`

Comment: Sorry that was just a mistake pasting the code. My code is correct. I don't get any error.

Comment: Then start checking return values. you have a lot of chained code that depends on success. never assume success when dealing with external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
$temp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['temp_name'];
                                  ^^^^
```

Should be `tmp_name`. Yay for some bright sparking attempting to save the universe by removing one vowel from one word, but neglecting to do so in the other.

Plus, unless you haven't shown it, you're simply assuming the upload succeeded. The FIRST thing you have to do with ANY upload is check the `['error']` parameter.

Comment: That was just a mistake while pasting the code. But on my original source code is correct. I did all the necessary verifications before reach this function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors in the code.

1. it should be `$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']` (not 'temp' but 'tmp')
2. `->save(dest, TRUE)` should be `->save($dest, TRUE)`

Also: if you want to get error messages, put this on top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Sorry I type the code here, didn't 'copy and past' Thats why the mistakes. Trying to fix. But thats not the cause at all.

Comment: you'll want to double check this `$FILES` wrong syntax. missing underscore.

Comment: But it's correct even on the original post. Didn't edit this part $temp_file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];

Comment: I'm not talking about what you're using @Wellyngton am talking about what Ronny put in his answer.